# Is there an onscreen gamepad that works similarly to virtualgamepad from Windows?

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen, gamepad

I'll been working on Ubuntu for some time,but I got a convertible laptop with touchscreen and I love it, but I need a virtual onscreen gamepad so I can play most games with touch.